# Unable to make connection to MongoDB using MongoDB Scala Driver

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query, mongodb-scala

I am using Scala driver for MongoDB to make a connection and insert a document in the class. I am following their official documentation as mentioned in this link. (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/2.6/getting-started/quick-tour/)

I am running MongoDB on the windows 10 and as standalone not in the cluster setup. When I run the scala code, I see following log entry and error and nothing happens.

**Log Info:**

```
373 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - Cluster created with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}

510 [main] INFO org.mongodb.driver.cluster - No server chosen by com.mongodb.async.client.ClientSessionHelper$1@702657cc from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

**Sbt File:**

```
ame := "TestModule"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.12.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-simple" % "1.7.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.6.0"
```

**Scala Code:**

```
import org.mongodb.scala._

object MongoDBManager {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={


    // Making connection with a database made in the MongoDB
    // Use a Connection String
    val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://localhost")

    // Connect with the Database
    val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("poc")

    //Get the Collection
    val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("poc_json")

    //make a sample json document
    val doc: Document = Document("_id" -> 2, "name" -> "MongoDB", "type" -> "database", "count" -> 1)

    // Insert the Document into the MongoDB.

    val observable: Observable[Completed] = collection.insertOne(doc)
    //Explicitly subscribe:
    observable.subscribe(new Observer[Completed] {

      override def onNext(result: Completed): Unit = println("Inserted")

      override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Failed")

      override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
    })



  }
}
```

Do anybody point out that what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and fixed it by adding `Thread.sleep(1000)` at the end of my program. Apparently it closes the connection before it finishes the operation and so nothing happens. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution though.